# accessing a map from Cassandra in R

Tags: r, serialization, dictionary, cassandra, key-value

I am using `rJava`/`DBI`/`RJDBC` in R in order to access some data stored via Cassandra.

Unfortunately I still have no way to extract data from the maps that are stored in a columnfamily.

For example, having the following columnfamily:

```
CREATE TABLE analytics.events (
    u bigint,
    unixtime bigint,
    id text,
    payload map<text, text>,
    type text,
    PRIMARY KEY (u, unixtime)
) 
CREATE INDEX events_type ON analytics.events (type);
```

I query it in R with the following query

```
results = dbGetQuery(casscon,"SELECT unixtime,type,payload FROM events WHERE u=2800 ORDER BY unixtime ASC;");
```

Unfortunately the map is in string form:

```
results[1,]$payload
[1] "{T=1408211680, Tl=0, Ts=0, _id=19, agent=Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; Event Build/IML12), i=1219384, ip=127.0.0.1, n=START_MENU, reg_id=, s=0, v=BV 2.0.22 BVC 25}"
```

Since it's not JSON, how can I effectively extract the values in the map? Is this another specific serialization format?